# Unknown string '%3Ca%20target=' in my site URL

Tags: php, javascript, http, httprequest

Sometimes, a string like `%3Ca%20target=` is getting attached to my site URL and this is causing unexpected behaviour.

The URL becomes like this:

**http://www.example.com/myhandler/mypage/mypage/%3Ca%20target=**

I am struggling to find out the reason behind this issue. Any hints?

Comment: It can be number of things, so you have to be more specific about your setup and situations in which this issue happens, to get your answer.

Comment: As a first check, ensure all links to *mypage* have the quotes around the `href` attribute properly closed.

Comment: Looks like `<a href="<a target=" ... etc`

Comment: Thanks you. I am checking my code, still could not find the exact location(since href is used in lot of places) of code which is causing this issue. I am using LAMP and client side JS/jQuery.

Comment: Are you actually seeing this happen in your browser or are you seeing these weird requests in your server logs?

Answer (score 1):

Well the URL-decoded translation of the end of your URL is `<a target=`. So somehow, your JS or something else must be putting HTML into the URL bar. You'll need to give the context of when this happens to the URL for any more help.